# What does parsing XML mean?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Can someone please explain to me what parsing XML means? And what does an XML parser do in general?

Comment: Parse = read and interpret....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means "reading" the XML file/string and getting its content according to the structure, usually to use them in a program.

For example if you have this XML fragment:

```
<root>
    <node1>value1</node1>
    <node2>value2</node2>
</root>
```

you may want to use these values in a data structure:

```
ClassRoot:
    node1: string
    node2: string
```

so that, in the end:

```
Object goofy = ClassRoot.new
parse(xml, goofy)
puts(goofy)
```

yelds something like:

```
goofy[node1='value1'; node2='value2']
```

There are many ways of doing so, like [DOM or SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).
You might want to investigate [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) and [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) as well, according to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

- [Google Define](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=v80&channel=fs&defl=en&q=define%3aXml+parser&sa=X&ei=RHhrTdvlB5Sq8QPzs8W_BQ&ved=0CBMQkAE)

> An XML parser is the piece of software
>   that reads XML files and makes the
>   information from those files available
>   to applications and programming
>   languages, usually through a known
>   interface like the DOM

- [XML Parsers List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aXML_parsers)

Answer (score 4):

Usually some information is stored in xml documents. In order to use this information in your program you have to parse it - read line by line or node by node and fetch pieces of information.

Answer (score 4):

An XML parser converts an XML document into an XML DOM object - which can then be manipulated with a JavaScript.

http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 2):

XML: Extensible Markup Language is a set of rules for encoding documents electronically. It is defined in the produced by the W3C and several other related specifications; all are fee-free open standards.

Parser: a computer program that divides code up into functional components; "compilers must parse source code in order to translate it into object code"